# Closures: Scope Chain Variables - Not sure how variables link up

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, closures

Really new to Javascript. This code is taken from MDN.

```
// global scope
var e = 10;
function sum(a){
  return function sum2(b){
    return function sum3(c){
      // outer functions scope
      return function sum4(d){
        // local scope
        return a + b + c + d + e;
      }
    }
  }
}

var s = sum(1);
var s1 = s(2);
var s2 = s1(3);
var s3 = s2(4);
console.log(s3) //log 20
```

When I try to input different variable names (EX below) they don't seem to work and I don't understand how everything links up together to spit out the answer 20.

```
// global scope
var e = 10;
function sum(a){
  return function sum2(b){
    return function sum3(c){
      // outer functions scope
      return function sum4(d){
        // local scope
        return a + b + c + d + e;
      }
    }
  }
}

var w = sum(1);
var x = s(2);
var y = s1(3);
var z = s2(4);
console.log(s3) //log 20
```

When I change it to this it also does not work. The console tells me that sa is not defined

```
// global scope
var e = 10;
function sm(a){
  return function sa(b){
    return function sb(c){
      // outer functions scope
      return function sc(d){
        // local scope
        return a + b + c + d + e;
      }
    }
  }
}

var s = sm(1);
var s1 = sa(2);
var s2 = sb(3);
var s3 = sc(4);
console.log(sc) //log 20
```

I can keep throwing out more examples that don't work. Someone, please help me understand how the first example works.

Comment: without all the variables it would look like this: `var s3 = sum(1)(2)(3)(4);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function sm(a){
  return function sa(b){
    return function sb(c){
      // outer functions scope
      return function sc(d){
        // local scope
        return a + b + c + d + e;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The function `sm` is taking one argument and is returning a function which takes one argument. The function `sm` returns is not named `sb`. Try to think of it as the return value of `sm` .
So, when you do

```js
var s = sm(1);
```

The returned function is stored in the variable `s`

Now if you want to run the second function (`sa` inside `sm`) you need to invoke s.

```js
var s1 = s(2);
```

The returned function (sb) is stored inside varibale s1.
Similarly,

```js
var s2 = s1(3);
var s3 = s2(4);
console.log(s3); // 20
```